# Is it possible to connect to ODBC data source from Jetbrains DataGrip?

Tags: odbc, datagrip

I need to connect to a legacy ODBC data source our client has provided. I need to analyze the same using Datagrip if possible. Is there any way to do this? Figure shows the screenshot of the ODBC configuration.

[image]

Comment: ODBC driver is not supported by java, please use suggestions from this thread as a workaround: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-2461

Answer (score 2):

ODBC driver is not supported by Java, please use suggestions from [this thread](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-2461/ODBC-or-Pervasive-driver#focus=Comments-27-1349445.0-0) as a workaround (example for pervasive):

> 1. Download jdbc driver for Pervasive database
> 2. In Database tool window open Datasource Properties dialog (Ctrl/Cmd+I shortcut)
> 3. Select + sign and choose to add a *Driver and Data Source* option
> 4. In that dialog go to driver settings and choose the jar you downloaded. According to documentation jdbc driver class name should be `com.pervasive.jdbc.v2.Driver`, so select it in Driver Settings
> 5. Then in Datasource properties settings enter connection settings (connection url, user, password in the JDBC URL Format like `jdbc:pervasive://<host>:<port>/<database>`